# IPython load balancer fails to read file

Tags: pandas, parallel-processing, ipython

I have just started using Load Balancer feature from the IPython notebook.

What I am trying to do is distribute the function of loading a large csv file over multiple cores.

Here is sample code to create load balanced view:

```
from IPython.parallel import Client
cluster = Client()
lb_view = cluster.load_balanced_view()
```

Then I try to read the csv with pandas through following shippet

```
@lb_view.parallel(block=True)
def read_csv(f):
    import pandas as pd
    data = pd.read_csv(f, iterator=True, chunksize=1e6)
    df = [chunk.groupby(by='ip_address').count() for chunk in data]
    return pd.concat(df)
```

It fails with very strange error (as if the file did not exist)

`CParserError: Passed header=0 but only 0 lines in file`

What I tried next using following snippet is to check if file is found on engines

```
@lb_view.parallel(block=True)
def read_csv(f):
    import os
    return os.path.exists(f)
```

The output is

```
[True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 False,
 True,
 False,
 False,
 False]
```

There are 31 results? some `True` and some `False`.  My cluster is running on 8 engines (8 cores) so I am confused what the above result mean. And what is the correct way to read csv using multiple cores?

(The reason I am going with the load balanced view is because I have tried reading the csv in the usual way and my CPU would jump to 100%)

Of course, file does exists, since trying to read it without load balanced view

```
pd.read_csv(f, nrows=5)
```

returns expected result

`ip_address  channel_spend   channels
0   100.0.0.131 1302.56 oo
1   100.0.0.144 55257.44    ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
2   100.0.0.92  1131.20 o
3   100.0.103.102   6059.20 oooo
4   100.0.103.111   6857.76 ooooooooo`

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the file, on your harddrive?  I dunno anything about your hardware or the ipython load balancer, but in a lot of situations 8 cores going at one harddrive is just going to lead to thrashing and no time savings...  maybe try 2 cores/engines and see if that works?

Comment: Why don't you try something simpler? (e.g. `print("Running this print statement")`). That would help you separate concerns (reading from disk i.e. I/O vs parallelization in IPython)

Comment: @JohnE, the file is on the harddrive. I makes sense to load the file on all 8 cores. Thanks. However, same problem occurs even when I start the cluster on two or even single core. Makes the change the idea of trying to use this approach all together. Perhaps load balancing is not for reading files

Comment: @Josh, thanks. I tried simply return a string statement. And it works fine so the problem is with IO and parallelization. I think I should try something else here

Comment: Reading the same file is ABSOLUTELY NOT a good use case for parallelization. If each thread was reading a DIFFERENT file, this could work. You should only be parallelizing work where no communication is needed between parallel tasks. Obviously reading a file requires a LOT of coordination between tasks. Read up on Embarrassingly Parallel wokrloads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel